# How to output python graphs from terminal?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am very new to Python. Just installed it yesterday on Ubuntu 15.04. Now I am trying to output a parabola from the terminal. As far I understand I can not output any drawing on terminal so how can I see the graph?

I did :
`sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib`

my code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# create 1000 equally spaced points between -10 and 10
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)

# calculate the y value for each element of the x vector
y = x**2 + 2*x + 2  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

it does not show error when i do `python parabola.py` but no output :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add plt.show() at the end of the code, to display the parabola.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show